# how to restrict the children element inside the parent element in css?

Tags: html, css

my css and html code is : https://jsfiddle.net/z2cc11yk/

html:

```
<div class="progressbar-container">
<div class="progressbar-text">125%</div>
<div class="progressbar-progress" style="background-color: red; width: 100%; transition: width 200ms ease 0s; height: 20px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="progressbar-container">
<div class="progressbar-text">50%</div>
<div class="progressbar-progress" style="background-color: rgb(11, 211, 24); width: 50%; transition: width 200ms ease 0s; height: 20px;"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
 .progressbar-progress{
background-color: rgb(11, 211, 24);
width: inherit;
transition: width 200ms ease 0s;
height: 100%;
position:absolute;

margin:0 10;
z-index: -2;
}
.progressbar-text{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position:absolute;
z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar-container{
border-style: solid;
height: 20px;
border-width:1px;
text-align:center;
width: 100%;
}
```

The issue is I use the absolute position for inside element, as I need to present the text on top of the progress bar.

But I find if 100% filled the childe element is larger than the parents element.

I mean the class progressbar-progress is larger than the progressbar-container.
How to restrict inside the progressbar-contain box?

Another question is why the height is filled, while the children elements width is larger than parents element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width will be fine with `position:relative` in `.progressbar-container` and height is given by you only the problem is when you use `position:absolute` in children element you need to use `position:relative` in parent element to place the children element according to parent.

```css
.progressbar-progress {
  background-color: rgb(11, 211, 24);
  width: inherit;
  transition: width 200ms ease 0s;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1849px;
  margin: 0 10;
  z-index: -2;
}
.progressbar-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar-container {
  border-style: solid;
  height: 20px;
  border-width: 1px;
  max-width: 1849px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-text">125%</div>
  <div class="progressbar-progress" style="background-color: red; width: 100%; transition: width 200ms ease 0s; height: 20px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-text">50%</div>
  <div class="progressbar-progress" style="background-color: rgb(11, 211, 24); width: 50%; transition: width 200ms ease 0s; height: 20px;"></div>
</div>
```

> Till the time `position:relative` is not there is parent element the child's height width is according to whole body thats why child element is greater then parent element after using `position:relative` in parent element the child's height width is according to parent div.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `position: relative` to `.progressbar-container`. Now `width` and `height` of child element are being calculated according to `body` tag.

Add `position: relative` to parent so that they calculate `width` and `height` correctly.

> Elements with `position: absolute` calculate their dimensions according to the nearest ancestor node with a position of `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

```css
.progressbar-progress{
  background-color: rgb(11, 211, 24);
  width: inherit;
  transition: width 200ms ease 0s;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  max-width: 1849px;
  margin:0 10;
  z-index: -2;
}
.progressbar-text{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar-container{
  border-style: solid;
  height: 20px;
  border-width:1px;
  max-width: 1849px;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-text">125%</div>
  <div class="progressbar-progress" style="background-color: red; width: 100%; transition: width 200ms ease 0s; height: 20px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-text">50%</div>
  <div class="progressbar-progress" style="background-color: rgb(11, 211, 24); width: 50%; transition: width 200ms ease 0s; height: 20px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is make the position in the `.progressbar-progress` class `relative`

```
.progressbar-progress{
    position:relative;
}
```